Are Aerial Screensavers stuttering in general or just on macOS Sequoia 15.1.1?
Ever since getting this M3 Max 16-inch MacBook Pro last December (2023), I have taken advantage of the generous space of the SSD to download all Aerial screensavers and set them up to rotate alongside the desktop wallpaper every 12 hours.
Since yesterday, I have noticed that while the screensavers are still generally smooth, the "camera" movement seems to stutter every few seconds or so. The movement begins smoothly and then makes a small jump, both on the internal display and on the external one I use (MateView 28").
Not knowing how to technically express this, I could describe it as if the framerate of the display dropped for a while, though I doubt that is the case. This is more noticeable when looking at the edges of the screen, but it is there in any case.
Another, possibly related thing, is that when I drag the compose-Mail window around, the text becomes noticeably blurry until the drag operation is over. This is not so evident in other apps.
Any idea of what this could be?

Does the 'stuttering' stop when you detach the external display?

No, it doesn't. It happens on both displays when external is connected and on main display when it isn't.
